# Js Adding a Map Iteration While Inside It

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was tweaking with js, and I was wondering if there is a way to add another element in an array that is being mapped inside one of the map iterations, to then make that vale be processed by the map.

Example:

```
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];

// Pass a function to map
var oneIter = true;
const map1 = array1.map((x) => {
  if (oneIter) {
    oneIter = false;
    array1.push(10);
  }
  
  return x * 2
});

console.log(array1);
console.log(map1);
// Expected output: Array [2, 8, 18, 32, 100], Actual output: Array [2, 8, 18, 32]
```

Thank you for your time.

Tried to add an element by simply pushing it during a js map iteration.

Comment: You will need to add another iteration

Comment: Do you want to understand why the actual o/p is coming in the question or do you want some logic to build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MDN for `.map()`:

> The map() method is a copying method. It does not alter this. However, the function provided as callbackFn can mutate the array. Note, however, that the length of the array is saved before the first invocation of callbackFn. Therefore:
> callbackFn will not visit any elements added beyond the array's initial length when the call to map() began.
> Changes to already-visited indexes do not cause callbackFn to be invoked on them again.
> If an existing, yet-unvisited element of the array is changed by callbackFn, its value passed to the callbackFn will be the value at the time that element gets visited. Deleted elements are not visited.

The same for `.forEach()` and I think for all other array methods.

And also a warning:

> Warning: Concurrent modifications of the kind described above frequently lead to hard-to-understand code and are generally to be avoided (except in special cases).

Mapping array elements generally should be pure without side effects. So probably that's one of the reasons why array methods don't support dynamic length during execution.

Use `for` loop for mutation logic.

If you want to use `.map()` anyway, just do the extra mapping after the first iteration:

```js
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];

let cb = (x, idx) => (idx || array1.push(10) && (cb = x => x * 2), x * 2);

const map1 = array1.map(cb);
map1.push(...array1.slice(map1.length).map(cb));

console.log(...array1);
console.log(...map1);
```

With `Array::reduce()`:

```js
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];

let cb = (x, idx) => (idx || array1.push(10) && (cb = x => x * 2), x * 2);

const [map1] = array1.reduce(([arr, len], item, idx) => 
  (arr.push(cb(item, idx), ...(idx === len - 1 ? array1.slice(len).map(cb) : [])), [arr,len]), [[],array1.length])

console.log(...array1);
console.log(...map1);
```